# MySql DECLARE variable syntax

Tags: mysql

I am moving from SQL Server to mySQL.

MSSQL I used to write below and execute them in one go.

```
Declare @d datetime
Select @d='2021-02-01'
Select * from tbl where createdt>@d
```

This can be executed without stored procedure

***Mysql:***

```
Declare d datetime
Select d='2021-02-01'
Select * from tbl where createdt>d
```

How do I do this in mysql work bench? It complains syntax error in DECLARE.

I am confused about the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @ in MySQL too, to use a user-defined variable.

You can do it as following without using any standard procedure or functions.

```
set @d='2021-02-01';
select * from tbl_name where createdt> @d;
```

You don't need to use declare clause here.
You can refer here: [Syntax reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql-how-to-declare-a-datetime-variable)

Comment: Then the type is string ?

Comment: I have tried the queries with a table having a column of date datatype and it's working fine.